# Converting jQuery forEach Function to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach

I was tasked with converting a jQuery function into plain JavaScript. The function is used to check if an element is within the viewport. If it is within the viewport take the data-bglazy attribute and add a background image style to that element using the value of that attribute. The function that needs converted is:

```
$.fn.isInViewport = function() {
    var elementTop = $(this).offset().top;
    var elementBottom = elementTop + $(this).outerHeight();

    var viewportTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

    return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;
  };

 $(window).on('resize scroll', function() {
    $('.bgLazy').each(function() {
      if ($(this).isInViewport()) {
        var lazyImg = $(this).attr('data-bglazy');
        $(this).css('background-image', 'url(' + lazyImg + ')');
      }
    });
  });
```

Currently what I have when trying to convert the above function to JavaScript:

```
function isInViewport(el){
    var elementTop = el.offsetTop;
    var elementBottom = elementTop + el.offsetHeight;

    var viewportTop = window.scrollTop;
    var viewportBottom = viewportTop + window.offsetHeight;

    return elementBottom > viewportTop && elementTop < viewportBottom;

  };

    var bgElements = document.querySelectorAll('.bgLazy');

    bgElements.forEach(bgElementLoop);

    function bgElementLoop(item, index) {
      if(item.isInViewport()){
        var lazyImg = item.getAttribute('data-bglazy');
        item.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + lazyImg + ')';
      }
    }


    window.addEventListener("resize, scroll", bgElementLoop);
```

I am trying to figure out which part I screwed up on when attempting to convert the jQuery function to JavaScript

EDIT:

I made a view changes after reading some of the comments. the isInViewport function is not changed, but what I did change is the following:

```
    var bgElements = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.bgLazy'));

    bgElements.forEach(bgElementLoop);

    function bgElementLoop(item, index) {
      if(item.isInViewport(item)){
        var lazyImg = item.getAttribute('data-bglazy');
        item.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + lazyImg + ')';
      }
    }

    window.addEventListener("resize", bgElementLoop);
    window.addEventListener("scroll", bgElementLoop);
```

So what I did here is changed the bgElements variable from

```
var bgElements = document.querySelectorAll('.bgLazy');
```

to

```
var bgElements = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.bgLazy'));
```

I then separated the resize and scroll event listeners into:

```
window.addEventListener("resize", bgElementLoop);
window.addEventListener("scroll", bgElementLoop);
```

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns a `NodeList`, not an array.

Comment: `window.addEventListener("resize, scroll", bgElementLoop);` you also shouldn't have the comma in the event string

Comment: for one `if(item.isInViewport())` should be `if(isInViewport(item))`

Comment: try `var bgElements = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.bgLazy'));` to use `forEach`

Comment: @DanielA.White - nodelist has a forEach method as well.

Comment: @SudhirBastakoti Or `Array.prototype.slice.call` to avoid an unnecessary array instantiation.

Comment: can everyone stop trying to convert nodelists to arrays. it's fine as is.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. that depends on which browser (version) you are using.  Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList for additional information

Comment: `"resize, scroll"` won't work in your event listener. in vanilla js you have to assign one event at a time.

Comment: is modernizing an option? if so, I would encourage you look into [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API). Here is the example from MDN page adapted to show the element change as it comes into view....just scroll the output window until the box shows up. https://jsfiddle.net/vf60mcdw/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a workign example with all my suggestions from the comments.

```js
function isInViewport(el) {
  var b = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  return b.top >= 0 &&
    b.left >= 0 &&
    b.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) &&
    b.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight);
};

var bgElements = document.querySelectorAll('.bgLazy');

function onScrollResize() {
  bgElements.forEach((item, index) => {
    if (isInViewport(item)) {
      var lazyImg = item.getAttribute('data-bglazy');
      setTimeout(() => item.innerHTML = 'loaded', 1000);
      item.style.backgroundImage = 'url("' + lazyImg + '")';
    }
  });
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", onScrollResize);
window.addEventListener("resize", onScrollResize);
window.addEventListener("scroll", onScrollResize);
```

```html
<div class='bgLazy' data-bglazy="http://i.imgur.com/rw0Jwpm.jpg">stuff</div><br>
<div class='bgLazy' data-bglazy="http://i.imgur.com/rw0Jwpm.jpg">stuff</div><br>
<div class='bgLazy' data-bglazy="http://i.imgur.com/rw0Jwpm.jpg">stuff</div><br>
<div class='bgLazy' data-bglazy="http://i.imgur.com/rw0Jwpm.jpg">stuff</div><br>
<div class='bgLazy' data-bglazy="http://i.imgur.com/rw0Jwpm.jpg">stuff</div><br>
<div class='bgLazy' data-bglazy="http://i.imgur.com/rw0Jwpm.jpg">stuff</div><br>
<div class='bgLazy' data-bglazy="http://i.imgur.com/rw0Jwpm.jpg">stuff</div><br>
<div class='bgLazy' data-bglazy="http://i.imgur.com/rw0Jwpm.jpg">stuff</div><br>
<div class='bgLazy' data-bglazy="http://i.imgur.com/rw0Jwpm.jpg">stuff</div><br>
<div class='bgLazy' data-bglazy="http://i.imgur.com/rw0Jwpm.jpg">stuff</div><br>
<div class='bgLazy' data-bglazy="http://i.imgur.com/rw0Jwpm.jpg">stuff</div><br>
<div class='bgLazy' data-bglazy="http://i.imgur.com/rw0Jwpm.jpg">stuff</div><br>
<div class='bgLazy' data-bglazy="http://i.imgur.com/rw0Jwpm.jpg">stuff</div><br>
<div class='bgLazy' data-bglazy="http://i.imgur.com/rw0Jwpm.jpg">stuff</div><br>
<div class='bgLazy' data-bglazy="http://i.imgur.com/rw0Jwpm.jpg">stuff</div><br>
<div class='bgLazy' data-bglazy="http://i.imgur.com/rw0Jwpm.jpg">stuff</div><br>
<div class='bgLazy' data-bglazy="http://i.imgur.com/rw0Jwpm.jpg">stuff</div><br>
<div class='bgLazy' data-bglazy="http://i.imgur.com/rw0Jwpm.jpg">stuff</div><br>
<div class='bgLazy' data-bglazy="http://i.imgur.com/rw0Jwpm.jpg">stuff</div><br>
```

Comment: And again, from the comments, this will not work in IE as NodeList does not implement `forEach`.  IE would need a polyfill.

Comment: I implemented this and it worked perfectly! Going with the above content for IE support I set up the bgElements variable using: Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.bgLazy'));

Comment: ie needs to die, and it won't die if we keep supporting it. only 2% of users use the very latest version of ie anyway.

Comment: Those kinds of generic statistics are meaningless. What matters is what **your** users are using. If you're building a tool for enterprises, hospitals, the government, retirees or a stubborn CEO then IE is definitely NOT dead and probably won't be dead any time soon.

Comment: it doesn't matter. it isn't even a real statistic. it's hyperbole meant to illustrate that the number of IE users in the wild is minuscule and generally not worth consideration. comments aren't for extended discussion. feel free to send me a chat invite.